# Mysterious RegionDistanceFunction::regp message

Tags: functions, bugs, warning-messages, regions, compile

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0** [CASE:4853257]

---

I encountered a strange problem with `RegionDistanceFunction`. Consider this list of points (I'm forced to use `Compress`, because with direct input the problem doesn't reproduce):

```
pts = Uncompress@"1:eJx11l1Ik1EYB3BNAwsqDLqwomZ+lCvNPtA+Bp0wuihvKr14T5lQtlzFClYxLWd+\
VfYJkVBZpF1ILMoIgojUi6n50dbMLZtZqQsv+hCDdtMH9p6HPWcHfHpBj/B75/u85/\
lzniXuO7rTbI6KirLF6r9yLbbjB6L1P6bpP607el31Fs4O/zlh3erTmATf3ecNATNnG/L1y6/\
A4hsz2os4Z4liHVRgnbgzn7Prc7c0zxpSIM7K6zu2cVboap6YP6xAcFK/\
NnE20OP02IIKlDpydm03cZaaNv43NKbASF/\
d3rZszq469euLAoaK243tmXpVYp1Q4Iq408jZrSJrdF5IgcvHOu3dyZwFOxZ4Fv1SIP9ncfb+hZx9FtVNKtAScm+\
8lsBZcYN9zBTLI7BevPg8zr6xH69K4hTob7mf5ZjDGa4S8E78pAT83/gsCVgNVhfZxHD9+\
D4S6sNvjDsgAfcI90wC7irusgTsA/ZFAnYOOykBe429l4DpwLREqgrnCfMlAROIiZSAmcUMS/\
D7mo509etbIt7nkPrwJMPBeI/GTJ6e+Bd2Bbzur4bSHo2NivcoV2Bi+oWSe90a+\
y7WWgWqyvJGeZfGskV1dQo4qkeePXipMW8ga3b0HQUazA83p3Rq7JKoyqlAzZPW340dGltRYGnKfaxCb6F/\
wKX3Q1TVRkAFrARkwZ4R8Nbw1JgeIOAi9J6A5SdnnqkcJ2AYEkmAUXwiY/dU+\
AQpIaBcrDkErIWUEOAT76ERUAs9JyBNVGUl4CP0nACHWKsIWAM9J6BfVHWTgPPQcwKWiaoeEfABek5AGawErIaeE/\
AGek7AOeg5AUuh5wQMQc8JOC3WmD1TYRWccAT0iaoSCDgL5xUBqZArAt5Drgg4BbkiIBNyRYAXckVADeSKgBTIFQGD\
kCsCSiFXBKyEXBHwGnJFQDXkioBkyBUBAciVAtVhsMNKQAbkigA35IqAKsgV8fAkyBUB7yBXBEBVMQVTIR1yRQBUlU\
BAJeSKgCWQKwIGIFcK4NGNR3lkfoQPezz8JeB4wHEhAQcKDhgJOIJwJEnAoYVDLPJNJjzmcOz998vdP0c/e4c=";
```

Now create a `RegionDistanceFunction` and apply it to the points:

```
df = RegionDistance[Line[pts[[{1, -1}]]]];

df /@ pts[[2 ;; -2]]
```

I get two `RegionDistanceFunction::regp` messages during the evaluation of this code:

> ```
> RegionDistanceFunction::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionDistanceFunction[Line[{Compile`$4,Compile`$4}],2,Sqrt[(-105.65+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2+(-103.317+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2]&].
> ```

What is even more strange, I don't get these messages when I use the `RegionDistanceFunction` inside of a `Function`:

```
df[#] & /@ pts[[2 ;; -2]]
```

Why does this happen? How can it be explained?

I'm using *Mathematica* 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64. The problem persists after restarting *Mathematica*.

---

### UPDATE

I've found that the problem is related to auto-compilation performed by `Map`, and can be boiled down to

```
df = RegionDistance[
   Line[Uncompress[
     "1:eJxTTMoPSmNiYGAoZgESPpnFJamMQAZIZF/g6cOzM6Mcsv+U5rldiXTAKQEAX1wVAA=="]]];

SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> 1}];

df /@ {{105., 103.}}
```

> ```
> RegionDistanceFunction::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionDistanceFunction[Line[{Compile`$1,Compile`$1}],2,Sqrt[(-105.65+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2+(-103.317+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2]&].
> ```

> ```
> RegionDistanceFunction::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionDistanceFunction[Line[{Compile`$1,Compile`$1}],2,Sqrt[(-105.65+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2+(-103.317+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2]&].
> ```

> ```
> {0.72321}
> ```

Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks something is going wrong with the automatic compilation process. You observe:

```
df /@ pts[[2 ;; -2]];
```

> RegionDistanceFunction::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionDistanceFunction[Line[{Compile`$8,Compile`$8}],2,Sqrt[(-105.65+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2+(-103.317+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2]&].

> RegionDistanceFunction::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionDistanceFunction[Line[{Compile`$8,Compile`$8}],2.,Sqrt[(-105.65+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2+(-103.317+Subscript[Slot[<<1>>], <<1>>])^2]&].

Increase the length to start automatic compilation:

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> 111];
df /@ pts[[2 ;; -2]];
```

I think this is worth reporting to support as a bug.

Comment: Why does wrapping the `RegionDistanceFunction` by `Function` prevent the bug to appear?

Comment: Reported to support as [CASE:4853257].